# binary tree insert function

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

this isn't working, does this look right to you guys?
I think the logic is right, but I could be totally wrong

anyone have any ideas?

This is just the insert function, it's only supposed to work for ints

```
void BST::Insert(int valueToInsert) {

    if (root == NULL) {
        root = new Node();
        root->val = valueToInsert;
        root->parent = NULL;
        root->left = NULL;
        root->right = NULL;

    } else {
        Node* tmp = new Node();
        tmp->val=valueToInsert;
        Node* trav = root;
        tmp->left=NULL;
        tmp->right=NULL;

        while (true) {   
            if((trav->val)>(trav->val)) {
                if (trav->right == NULL) {
                    trav->right = tmp;
                    tmp->parent = trav;
                    tmp->right = NULL;
                    tmp->left = NULL;                  
                    break;
                } else {
                    trav = trav->right;
                    continue;
            }
        }

        if ((tmp->val)<(trav->val)) {
            if (trav->left == NULL) {
                trav->left = tmp;        
                tmp->parent = trav;
                break;
            }else {
                trav = trav->left;
                continue;
            }
        }
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following looks suspicious:

```
           if((trav->val)>(trav->val)) {
               ^^^^        ^^^^
```

Was the first `trav` meant to be `tmp`?

Comment: oh haha, yeah that's a big derp
still, it onyl inserts up to 1 value then it just goes in an infinite loop, anything else you see?

Comment: alright, i fixed that but it gets in an infinite loop adding 10.
numbers inserted are: 15,10,12,5,4,6,8,14,11,20,25,30

Answer (score 0):

```
while (true) {


                if((trav->val)>(trav->val)) {
```

Right below the while condition trav->val is being compared to trav->val.
This is not the intent, I guess.

Comment: oh haha, yeah that's a big derp still, it onyl inserts up to 1 value then it just goes in an infinite loop, anything else you see?

Comment: Are same values being used? If, for example, you have value 3 at the root and you try to insert 3 again, it goes to an infinite loop. To overcome this situation, instead of the second if statement in the loop, you can use a simple else.

Comment: nah, numbers inserted are:
15,10,12,5,4,6,8,14,11,20,25,30

it continously adds 10.

Comment: I can't see any other mistake with bare eyes. What is your development environment? Can't you use a debugger?